How are higher order complex derivatives and higher order partial derivatives related, quantitatively?
Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on a domain $U\subset \mathbb{C}$, then it has a complex derivative $f^{(n)}$ at any order. Meanwhile, using canonical identification $\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{R}^2$ we can write $f=u+iv$, where $u, v$ are both real-valued functions in terms of two real variables. This enables us to consider a different sort of derivatives, namely partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$. And there should be some connections between these partial (including higher-order partial) derivatives and the complex ones.
Since there are so many partial derivatives but just one complex derivative at each order, I hope to find a formula solely involving $f^{(n+m)}$ to represent the partial derivatives $\partial _x^n\partial_y^m u$ and $\partial _x^n\partial_y^m v$. I'm even conjecturing that $\partial _x^n\partial_y^m (u+ i v)$ can only be one of these forms: $\pm f^{(n+m)}, \pm \overline{f^{(n+m)}}, \pm i f^{(n+m)}, \pm i \overline{f^{(n+m)}}$.
At order $n=1$, this is exactly the famous Cauchy-Riemann equations: $\partial_x u =\partial_y v =\Re f^{(1)}$, $\partial_y u=- \Im f^{(1)}$ and $\partial_x v =\Im f^{(1)}$.
At order $n=2$, things become murkier but still solvable. We know that $f^{(1)}$ is  holomorphic, so Cauchy-Riemann equations apply automatically to $\partial_x u$ and $\partial_x v$. After some tedious calculations I write down the Hessian matrices
$\partial^2 u =\begin{pmatrix} \Re f^{(2)} & -\Im f^{(2)} \\ -\Im f^{(2)} & -\Re f^{(2)}\end{pmatrix}$ and $\partial^2 v =\begin{pmatrix} \Im f^{(2)} & \Re f^{(2)} \\ \Re f^{(2)} & -\Im f^{(2)}\end{pmatrix}$.
As order gets higher and higher I'm not sure how this pattern will evolve. I  was stuck with this problem initially while trying to prove $u$ and $v$ are smooth. Soon I found it too complicated to calculate the partial derivatives at every order, and I avoided it by induction on $n$ in the claim $u\in C^n(D)$. If $u\in C^n(D)$, then every (first-order) partial derivative will be in $C^n(D)$, implying $u\in C^{n+1}(D)$. Nevertheless, it's fun and instructive to ponder the accurate form of higher order partial derivatives.

What the Cauchy-Riemann equations tells you as a consequence as what you wrote is that you actually have, for all holomorphic functions $f$:
$$\tag{$*$}f' = \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f = -i\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f$$
In particular, this includes the successive derivatives of a given function $f$, so that:
$$f^{(n)} = \displaystyle\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n} f = (-i)^n\displaystyle\frac{\partial^n}{\partial y^n} f$$
This might seem weird but complex analysis is quite the beautiful rabbithole of oddities. Anyway, this implies that we have the following formula for example:
$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\displaystyle\frac{\partial^m}{\partial y^m} f = i^m f^{(n+m)}$$
which demonstrates your conjecture, though the conjugate of $f$ can't intervene since it's not holomorphic in most cases.
Moreover, we have:
$$f^{(n)} = \displaystyle\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n} (u + iv) = \displaystyle\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}u + i\displaystyle\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n} v \overset{\text{if }n \geqslant 1}{=} \displaystyle\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}u - i\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\displaystyle\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial x^{n-1}} u$$
And that's only an example of the expressions and equations you can establish.
Now, for the smoothness of $u$ and $v$, it's pretty simple: from $(*)$, we know that $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u$ is the real part of $f'$, and the same can be said about $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x} v$, $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y} u$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y} v$ mutatis mutandi, thus, since $f'$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$, $u$ and $v$ are of class $\mathcal{C}^2$. An induction using the same argument but replacing $f$ with $f^{(n)}$ at each step grants you the desired smoothness for $u$ and $v$.
Another fact which may help you is the following refinement:
$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u = \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y} v = \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x} v = -\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} u$$
so that $u$ is harmonic, i.e.:
$$ \Delta u = \displaystyle\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u + \displaystyle\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}u= 0$$
The same can be done with $v$, which means that both $u$ and $v$ are harmonic, which is much stronger than pure smoothness (note that we could have stopped after the initial step in the aforemntioned induction, as $\mathcal{C}^2$ and harmonic imply $\mathcal{C}^\infty$).
This lets you swap any even number of $x$-derivatives with the same number of $y$-derivatives up to a mere sign change for formulas involving $\displaystyle\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n} \displaystyle\frac{\partial^m}{\partial y^m} u$ or the same with $v$.
With that and with the CR equations, you can thus, up to some power of $i$, make all formulas involving such terms come down to a combination of $\displaystyle\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}u$'s and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\displaystyle\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial x^{n-1}} u$'s.

In a formal setting of $\mathbb C \times C \mapsto \mathbb C \times C $ with two complex variables $x + i y = z, x- i y = w$, a complex differentiable function $\{z,w\} \mapsto f(z,w)$, f is independent of $w$, $$\partial_w f(z,w) =0.$$ It follows that $$\partial_z^n f = \nabla^{(n,0)}(f)(z,w) $$ is the n-th formal algebraic 1-d derivative wrt. to the first argument.
This statement is equivalent to the rule, to differentiate wrt to the real part $\partial_x$ (or the imaginary part  $\partial_{i y}$)
$$\partial_z^n f(z) = f^{(n)}(x) \quad \text{with}\  x \to x + i y $$
The inverse for the integral is true, too, the antiderivative of order n is the repeated contour integral along any contour between two points.
The differential algebra in $\mathbb R^2$ by the Cauchy-Riemann PD equations in the Gaussian plane make simple things so difficult, because the trivial complex algebra takes place in $\mathbb R^4$ with two independent mirror copies of th algebra of holomorphic and anitholomorphic functions.
Things become clearer if the differential complex is identified as the simplest form of a Clifford algebra, that is: $x=\Re z$ is a real scalar and $e_1 = i$ is the basis vector of  a 1-d real euclidean space with scalar product $e_1 \cdot e_1 = -1 \in \mathbb R$.
